# Batch file modification in Talend

Tags: batch-file, talend

I have designed a job to copy data from excel file to SQL tables. Now I want to export this job and modify it to more user friendly.

I have used 1 context variables in my job. Now I want to modify my batch file in a way that I can run it using another batch file which has values for these context variables.

My generated batch file is job1.bat

At the end of it I have removed --context=default and have added..
--context_param Database=%1 %*

now I have another batch file Test3.bat which has it texts as...
job1.bat Test3

Where Test3 is the name of the database with which I want to work.
But its not working.

What do I need to change in these two files?

Comment: This is 2 separate questions. Please edit one of the questions out and open another one.

Comment: All right. I have separated them.
Initially I had a restriction to post only 1 question in 90 minutes that's why I posted them in one.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

Main file, named 'job1.bat' has..
... --context_param contextvar1=%1 --context_param contextvar1=%2 --context_param contextvar1=%3

Another file has..
job1.bat value1 value2 value3

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't see the point in this unless it's to limit access to the original batch file that kicks the job off.

Comment: I have created it for someone who won't be having much idea about talend. And I wouldn't like them to remember that complex syntax with --context_param... .
Instead they can just define context variables values in specified order in a different batch file. And copy excel entries to their desired database.

Comment: If they can follow specific instructions to put context variables in a set order then I'd guess they can probably follow the same instructions for the original batch file and at least there they get the benefit of being told the context var name that they are setting. Each to their own though.

Comment: Fair enough. Got your point.
Only benefit with creating another batch file is that they can edit/refer it easily.
It doesn't have that initial commands with complex sentences.